# Flexbox element with <svg> as first child gets mis-aligned upwards

Tags: css, svg, flexbox, vertical-alignment

If an element has `display: inline-flex` and contains an `<svg>` as first child, the element is pushed up.

Use case: A button that can have an `<svg>` icon as children. Before, after or in the middle of the text.

With [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) we can align the icon and add spacing between icon and text, regardless of which order they appear in (and without having to wrap the text in `<span>`).

**BUG:** However, as you can see, the button that has the icon on the left (i.e. `<svg>` as first child) is moved up compared to the other two!

```css
button {
  /* This will center align the icon (vertically)
   * and add 5px margin on each side of it */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;

  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
    Text
  </button>
  <button>
    Text
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Without `inline-flex` to control the layout, the buttons are aligned with each other (but the icons are not center aligned inside the buttons).

```css
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
    Text
  </button>
  <button>
    Text
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `vertical-align: middle` to the parent element, it will fix not be moved up even if it has an `<svg>` as first child.

```css
button {
  /* This will center align the icon (vertically)
   * and add 5px margin on each side of it */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;

  /* Align correctly even if the first child is an svg */
  vertical-align: middle;

  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
    Text
  </button>
  <button>
    Text
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button>
    Text
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
    text
  </button>
  <button>
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
    Text
    <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="hotpink" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: just found your answer and it helped me! but how is this working? i'd be happy to know!

Comment: Is there a particular part of how it works you're wondering about, @birdy90? I've tried to explain the CSS with comments, but let me know if it is confusing.

Comment: I meant - why did `vertical-align` helps? It seems, I've already found the solution. That's because inline item align itself by the baseline. It takes button's first child as reference to alignment. If the first is a letter - then letters aligned as intended. But if there is an SVG icon, then button is shifted up, as icon's bottom is lower than the baseline. So `vertical-align` says to ignore it. As long as it is a row of buttons - everything is fine. But if we put a button with icon and label inside some text, we'll see that button label is lower than another text. Thank you for your help!